# Tranferring Apps from 1 ipad to another

Tags: ipad

I received an Ipad from my employer for work.  I also have a personal Ipad.  I set up 2 different apple ids, one for work and one for personal use.  I now want to return my work Ipad but tranfer the apps etc to my personal Ipad.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is, unfortunately, no way to *transfer* apps between Apple IDs. The closest thing you can do is switch between the Apple IDs on your personal iPad. You will have to use your *work* Apple ID to download the apps. First you will have to login using your work Apple ID (Settings.app -> iTunes & App Stores -> Account) on your iPad then redownload whatever you want on your personal iPad.

Please understand one important thing that once there is an app update, or if they change your work Apple ID's email or password, you will have a problem in the future.

I suggest that you redownload all the apps using your own Apple ID.